# splitting text to create new variable

Tags: r, text, split

I have this first dataset, and I want to create the desired dataset by splitting the text in the first dataset, I'm wondering how could I do this:

Basically the new variables will be split after "XYZ-1" or "AAA-2".
I appreciate all the help there is!Thanks!

1st dataset:

```
Name <- c("A B XYZ-1 Where","C AAA-2 When","ABC R SS XYZ-1 Where")
x <- data.frame(Name)
```

desired dataset:

```
Name <- c("A B XYZ-1 Where","C AAA-2 When","ABC R SS XYZ-1 Where")
Study <- c("A B XYZ-1","C AAA-2","ABC R SS XYZ-1")
Question <- c("Where","When","Where")
x <- data.frame(Name,Study,Question)
```

```
Name                      Study             Question

A B XYZ-1 Where           A B XYZ-1         Where       
C AAA-2 When              C AAA-2           When        
ABC R SS XYZ-1 Where      ABC R SS XYZ-1    Where
```

Comment: Are "XYZ-1" or "AAA-2" the only two values to split after? Or what's the general pattern?

Comment: Yes, these are the only two values to split after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `separate` - pass a regex lookaround in `sep` to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) that follows three upper case letters and a `-` and a digit (`[A-Z]{3}-\\d`) and that precedes an uppercase letter (`[A-Z]`)

```
library(tidyr)
separate(x, Name, into = c("Study", "Question"), 
     sep = "(?<=[A-Z]{3}-\\d)\\s+(?=[A-Z])", remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
                  Name          Study Question
1      A B XYZ-1 Where      A B XYZ-1    Where
2         C AAA-2 When        C AAA-2     When
3 ABC R SS XYZ-1 Where ABC R SS XYZ-1    Where
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you kindly explain this part "(?<=[A-Z]{3}-\\d)\\s+(?=[A-Z])" please?

Comment: @Bruh - you may want to see this Stack Overflow question: [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution using `strsplit` with regex:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(x$Name, ' (?=[^ ]+$)', perl=TRUE)) %>% 
  data.frame()
colnames(df) <- c("Study", "Question")
cbind(x[1], df)
```

```
                  Name          Study Question
1      A B XYZ-1 Where      A B XYZ-1    Where
2         C AAA-2 When        C AAA-2     When
3 ABC R SS XYZ-1 Where ABC R SS XYZ-1    Where
```